# 2 NICs Windows 2k8 Server DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nic, dhcp-server

Hi I have 2 NICs on my Windows 2008 R2 Server and I want to be able to have 1 NIC connected to the router (Wan) and 1 connected to a standalone switch (Lan) and act as an DHCP server. I want it to act like its sharing the internet from the Wan to the Lan but be able to manage the ip addresses with DHCP server. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use RRAS to handle the routing and you want to use the DHCP server role to assign addresses. Just bind DHCP to the internal interface and configure it as normal. No magic here, both are well documented on Technet.